# What are the differences between const and volatile pointer in C?

Tags: c

What are the differences between const and volatile pointer in C?

Comment: They are completely different. Have you even glanced at the documentation?

Comment: @Anon: but they have the opposite context. The question is legitimate for a newbie. +1 to balance.

Comment: @the_drow:  They look opposite, but `const volatile` is a perfectly legitimate cv-qualifier, meaning "The program isn't changing it, but something else might, or doing the access might do something in itself".

Comment: True but that's way over a newbie's head. Memory barriers and other low level nightmares are the idioms of much more experienced developers. To a newbie they seem like opposites.

Comment: Newbies must be immediately encouraged not to think of them as opposites, even if they aren't handling "low level nightmares". Otherwise, they might end up thinking that `const` means you (and the compiler) can assume that the value can't change, which is emphatically not the case when pointers are involved. For example, a `const char` can't change value, but the char pointed to by a `const char*` can validly change value while your back is turned (e.g. because of aliasing).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference really comes down to the difference between `const` and `volatile`. The only things these two concepts have in common is syntax. `const` is compiler-enforced and says "the programmer can not change this." `volatile` says "this data might be changed by someone else" and so the compiler will not make any assumptions about that data. Without `volatile` the compiler might say "I put this data from memory into a register, and since I haven't done anything to that data, I'm sure it's the same and I don't need to read it into the register again." When the data is marked as `volatile` the compiler won't make such an assumption (because someone else might have changed the data) and so it will reread the data into the register.

Now, are you asking for the difference between

```
int *const p;
```

and

```
int *volatile q;
```

or the difference between

```
const int* p;
```

and

```
volatile int* q;
```

In the former case: `p` is a pointer to an `int` and where that pointer points can not be changed by the programmer whereas `q` is a pointer to an `int` and where that pointer points could be changed by someone other than the programmer so the compiler makes no assumptions about that pointer.

So:

```
int *const p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
int *volatile q = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 17; // legal;
p = (int*)malloc(sizoef(int)); // not legal
*q = 17; // legal;
q = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // legal
```

In the latter case: `p` is a pointer to an `int` and what `p` is pointing to can not be changed by the programmer whereas `q` is a pointer to an `int` and what `q` is pointing to could be changed by someone other than the programmer so the compiler makes no assumptions about that data.

```
int i = 17;
int j = 34;
const int *p = &i;
volatile int *q = &i;
*p = 51; // not legal
p = &j; // legal
*q = 51; // legal
q = &j; // legal
```

Comment: Another legitimate use for `volatile` is when the act of accessing the data is significant itself, which is reasonably likely in memory-mapped I/O.  In 1.9(6) of the Standard, "observable behavior" is defined as "the sequence of reads and writes to `volatile` data and calls to library I/O functions."

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explanation of those two concepts

*The const keyword specifies that the pointer cannot be modified after initialization; the pointer is protected from modification thereafter.*

*The volatile keyword specifies that the value associated with the name that follows can be modified by actions other than those in the user application. Therefore, the volatile keyword is useful for declaring objects in shared memory that can be accessed by multiple processes or global data areas used for communication with interrupt service routines.*

It comes from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/145yc477.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `const` or `volatile` applies to the pointee, not the pointer itself.

`const` means you're not allowed to modify the pointee via that pointer.

`volatile` means somebody/something else might modify the pointee, even though your code doesn't. It also means that writing to the variable might do something more than just store a value to be retrieved the next time that variable is used. As a result, any time your code reads or writes a volatile value, the compiler is obliged to generate code that reads from (or writes to) actual memory, not just (for example) allocates a register for temporary use, and reads/writes the register.

Edit: Note that even though you're not allowed to modify the data via a `const` pointer, the data may still be modified by other means. In fact, there are times that you can have a pointee that's both `const` *and* `volatile`, which means you can't change it, but somebody else might.

Comment: It depends if it's `const char * p` or `char * const p`. You can quite reasonably have `const char * const p`.

Answer (score 1):

A const pointer (i.e. `const char* s = ..`) points to data that can *not* be modified. A volatile pointer (i.e.`volatile char* s = ...`) hints the compiler not to cache the data the pointer refers to in CPU registers, or elsewhere. Instead, they're reread from their original memory location every time they're needed. This is needed if the contents of the data might change outside the compiler's scope, for example through a second thread modifying it.

Be careful, `const char*` and `char* const` are different things, same for the `volatile`qualifier. If you're unsure, look them up.