# Usage wise difference between const & volatile qualifier in C?

Tags: c, volatile

I have already gone through the answer of question @ 
 [What are the differences between const and volatile pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089464/what-are-the-differences-between-const-and-volatile-pointer-in-c) 
I understand the explanation that:

The const modifier means that this code cannot change the value of the variable, but that does not mean that the value cannot be changed by means outside this code.
However, volatile says "this data might be changed by someone else" and so the compiler will not make any assumptions about that data.

Which implies that both type of variables can be changed by external event.

But,then where is the difference in usage of const & volatile?

In C, does compiler optimizations work for const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

volatile and const are different in many ways, they are two distinctively different features.

Declaring a variable just as const never means "I expect this variable to be modified outside the program", I'm not sure where you got that idea from. If you expect a const variable to be modified outside the code, it must be declared as `volatile const` or the compiler may assume that the variable is never changed.

By default, plain const variables are just like any kind of variable, they simply can't be modified by the program itself.

Just as for plain variables, const variable behavior depends a lot on in which scope they are declared. Most often they are declared at file scope and then they behave as other variables with static storage duration, except they are (likely) saved at a different part of the memory. If they are declared at local scope, they may change from time to time when the function where they reside is called.

So there are plenty of cases where const variables may be optimized. One common optimization is "string pools", where the compiler checks if the same constant string literal appears twice in the code, and then uses the same address for them. Had you expected such strings to be changed from an external source, but didn't declare them as volatile, you'd get strange bugs.

As for volatile variables, they may be modified by external sources, but they may also be modified by the program, unlike const variables.

Comment: Hi Lundin,
Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: @Arti Hello. If you consider an answer correct, or at least the most helpful, [click the check mark next to that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to accept it as the correct answer to your question. You should do this with the [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1354398/arti) you have previously asked as well. Sometimes you don't get any good answers and then it is fine to not accept any of them, but to never accept any answers at all is considered rude on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Lundin, yeah sure. 
Can you plz clear one more related doubt, I agree that I should not expect const being modified outside the program(or by external event), but external events can still modify it outside,unexpectedly. I mean is there any strict mechanism or compiler action, which prevents const to be modified outside unexpectedly?

Comment: @Arti There is the case where const variables reside in RAM but are written to accidentally by a bug. To prevent against that, modern CPUs have virtual memory hardware support, yielding a hardware exception should it happen.

Comment: @Arti Apart from that, const variables are only modified externally if it makes sense that they are modified. Examples are read-only hardware registers and non-volatile memory (flash, eeprom etc) which are written to through boot loaders or flash programming algorithms. That is always something that the programmer intended and therefore it doesn't make any sense to prevent such variables from getting modified.

Answer (score 1):

Objects with `const`-qualified type are objects like other objects that you may declare in your program, only that you don't have the right to modify them. The underlying object may change for example by aliasing and the compiler has to take care, as for all other objects if such events could have happend. For example

```
void toto(double const* pi, double* x) {
  printf("%g %g\n", *pi, *x);
  printf("%g %g\n", *pi, *x);
  *x = 5.0;
  printf("%g %g\n", *pi, *x);
}
```

Here it is perfectly ok to call `toto` with something like `toto(&a, &a)` and so inside the function `pi` and `x` point to the same memory. For the second `printf` the compiler can assume since it did no store in the mean time that the values of `*pi` and `*x` have not changed. But for the third `printf` it cannot foresee if `*pi` has changed so it has to reload the value from memory.

`volatile` is different from that.

```
void tutu(double volatile* pi, double* x) {
  printf("%g %g\n", *pi, *x);
  printf("%g %g\n", *pi, *x);
}
```

Here, for the second `printf` as before the compiler can assume that `*x` hasn't changed, but for `*pi` it *must* assume that it could have and *must* reload it from memory. Use cases for `volatile` are much rarer in daily programmers life, they mainly concern objects that

- might represent some hardware address
- that could change in an interrupt handler
- under some `setjmp/longjmp` mechanism
- or by a different thread

Comment: It is better to avoid the term “`const` object”. There is no such thing in the C standard, and this suggests a notion that it is the object that has the `const` property. In the C standard, it is a type, not an object, that may be const-qualified, and an lvalue may not be changed through a const-qualified type. This makes it clearer that it is the type through which an object is referred to that controls whether it is read-only or not, not the object, and hence makes it clearer that an object may be read-only when accessed one way and not read-only when accessed another way.

Comment: @Eric, you are right for what I wrote, see my edit. But your are not completely right for the global picture. Objects have types, either the one by which they were declared (normal "variables") or the first complete type through which they where accessed (e.g if an object is allocated through `malloc`).

Comment: @Eric: C99 uses the phrase "const object" twice that I can find -- once in an example and once in a note. I think that this is intended to be synonymous with the phrase in 6.7.3/5, "an object defined with a const-qualified type", otherwise the remarks made do not follow. So, there is such a thing as a "const object" in the C standard, and it means what Jens uses it to mean.

Comment: (a) C 2011 cancels and replaces C 1999. (b) Examples are not part of the normative part of the standard, per paragraph 6 in the Foreward. (c) The occurrences of “const object” in C 1999 were changed in 2011 for good reason: The term is not defined and conveys the wrong impression. If you want to claim a mechanical adherence to an unstated part of an obsolete standard, fine, there is no law preventing you from doing so. If you want to promote the finest understanding and use the terms as they are actually defined, then you should think again.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I don't see what you are after. C11 clearly uses the term of "object type" and this cannot be understood much differently than the type of an object. In 6.7.9 it even talks of "the type of the entity to be initialized" in the constraint section. And then in the sematics section it talks of "objects of structure and union type", and generally clearly uses the concept of the type of an object.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last draft of C11 that I have is n1570, which still uses the term "const object" exactly as C99 does. The idea that everyone must pretend to stop understanding this perfectly well-known term, whose meaning has been well defined for over a decade is... peculiar. Even if that idea comes from the standards committee, I think it's too late for them to make us stop using "const object" as an abbreviation for "object defined with a const-qualified type", which is the only thing it has ever meant.

Comment: It may be of interest that C++ needs rather more effort to define "const object", the existence of `new` makes things more complicated.

Comment: @SteveJessop, n1570 is the closest you can get. The published standard has no textual differences.

Comment: @Jens: well, Eric claimed that this specific text was changed, so I assumed a last-minute (well, last-6-months given how fast ISO works) editorial change. As he says, examples and notes are informative, so maybe the editor of C11 was free to change them without issuing a formal draft? But if you have the published text and you're saying there are no differences then that's a good ol'-fashioned disagreement about the contents of a document, someone is flat wrong ;-)

Comment: The reason there is a difference is that a type, particularly the const qualification, is not in generally permanently attached to an object. A single object may be accessed through different types, sometimes in the same statement. Consider `void Add(const int *a, const int *b, int *c) { *c = *a + *b; }`. In this function, **`*a` is not a const object**. It may be called with `int x = 3, y = 4; Add(&x, &y, &x);`, causing `x` to be both accessed and modified in the same statement. The case where an object is defined with const-qualified type is only a subset of `const` usage.

Comment: Right, `*a` is a const lvalue expression denoting a potentially non-const object. That actually is non-const for your example call.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I know all of that, why are you insisting on this? Still, contrary to what you claim, C attaches a type to an object. Sometimes your are accessing an object through a different type, as in your example with the function call, and so what?

Comment: @JensGustedt: “Object type” is defined to distinguish it from “function type”. It is a property of a type, not a characteristic of an object. 3.15 1 defines an “object” as a region of storage, without a type. The note there says an object may be interpreted as having a type **when referenced**. 3.19 ratifies this. 6.3.2.1 1 tells us that, when an object is said to have a particular type, it is specified **by the lvalue used to designate the object**. It is very clear: The C standard avoids attaching a type to an object itself; it is the lvalue that conveys the type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, have you re-read the section that I indicated, 6.7.9 on assignment? It clearly speaks of types of objects.

Comment: @JensGustedt: No, per my comment that I was writing while you wrote that, C does **not** attached a type to an object. It goes to some effort to avoid that and specifically states that the type used to interpret and object comes from an lvalue. The C standard was clearly carefully designed in this way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, please look at 6.7.9 and see if you can maintain that clain.

Comment: 6.5 also speaks at some length about the "effective type" of an object. So even a dynamically-allocated object can have a type -- its effective type. This can change when the object is modified. C does attach a type to an object (derived from the lvalue used to write it). The strict aliasing rules are then expressed in terms of the relationship between the effective type *of the object* and the type of the expression used to access it. So if the C standard did attempt to avoid attaching a type to an object then it palpably failed.

Comment: @JensGustedt: 6.7.9 speaks of the type of an entity. It does not speak  explicitly of the type of an object and, to the extent it does speak of the type of an object, it is because an object is being initialized through a particular lvalue. The only thing to gather here is that natural language is sometimes awkward and uses colloquial expressions. The standard has explicitly and clearly distinguished objects (storage) from types (specified by lvalues) as shown by my previous citations. Why would you think a casual use of language in the standard overrides explicit statements?

Comment: @Eric: The "entity" being initialized is an object so "the type of the entity" is the "the type of the object". You can't say that C very carefully avoids doing something, and then when it's pointed out that it does in fact do it ignore that use by declaring it "colloquial". The language used in the standard is what it is (albeit perhaps should be different in your opinion and/or that of the authors).

Comment: @SteveJessop: You are arguing for the purpose of establishing that you are “correct”, not for understanding the standard. Think again about what you are trying to accomplish. The point I am making is that the specifications about `const` behavior all revolve around what you can do through a specific lvalue and that this is because one object can be accessed through both a const-qualified type and through a non-const qualified type. Thinking of the object has having constness, rather than the lvalue, leads to incorrect deductions such as thinking an object of a const lvalue cannot be modified.

Comment: @Eric: quite the reverse. Thinking about the object having constness *prevents* making the mistake, by explicitly informing learners of C that the object is const or not (and if const cannot change unless also volatile) independently of whether a particular lvalue referring to it is const or not. I am arguing for the purpose of establishing a truth about the standard, that is an abstraction useful for understanding the standard. You are quibbling about whether or not the standard explicitly uses this abstraction, and if so whether those uses we've found so far are "awkward".

Comment: And most importantly, specifications about `const` *do not* "all revolve around what you can do with a specific lvalue". The statement in 6.7.3/6 about UB on attempting to modify "an object defined with const-qualified type" (which Jens and I and the C and C++ standards all refer to as a "const object" and you don't) has nothing to do with any lvalues later used to refer to the object, only on its definition. Saying that the object doesn't have constness works to obscure this important fact. It has constness if and only if it's defined with constness.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You have just made the mistake I was trying to get people to avoid by having the wrong mental model. I just showed an example where your so-called const object does change.

Comment: @SteveJessop: In the `Add` code in a previous comment, the value of `*a` changes even though `*a` has type `const int`. E.g., `printf("%d\n", *a); *c = *a + *b; printf("%d\n", *a);` would show two different numbers.

Comment: @Eric: that again? Nonsense. As I have already said above, the lvalue expression `*a` has const type. The object which it denotes is `x`. It was not defined with a const-qualified type, and it is not "my so-called const object". I do not call it a const object, and I never have, and if you hadn't said that I did then my message that an object referred to by a const lvalue can change would not have been obscured.

Comment: I say "nonsense": of course it's true what you say about the code that the value of `*a` changes because of the assignment to `*c`. What you say about me: having made a mistake; having the wrong mental model; calling `*a` a "const object"; that it is better to avoid ascribing constness to an object; are all incorrect deductions on your part.

Comment: I maintain my assertion that propagating the mental model of a “const object” will cause people to make mistakes such as expecting `printf("%d\n", *a); *c = *a + *b; printf("%d\n", *a);` to print the same value twice and that being clearer and more precise about the C model of const will lead to fewer programming errors.

Comment: I maintain my assertion that propagating the mental model of a “const object” will cause people to make mistakes such as expecting `printf("%d\n", *a); *c = *a + *b; printf("%d\n", *a);` to print the same value twice and that being clearer and more precise about the C model of const will lead to fewer programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

'const' tells the compiler that the value is never changed, not by the program and not by someone else. When something is const, the compiler will optimize the code accordingly, and will usually replace the variable with constants in code. So even if it changes outside, the program may never know.

'volatile', on the contrary tells the compiler that the variable can be changed from the outside anytime, and then the compiler will not perform such optimizations, as putting the var in a register, but will always read it from memory, in case it changed.

Comment: No, wrong. A `const` qualified object can be changed from "outside".

Comment: `const` is silent about whether an object may be changed in ways unknown to the implementation (not necessarily external to the program). If an lvalue is only `const`, the object may not be so changed. This is because that is the default, not because it is `const`. If an lvalue is both `const` and `volatile`, then it may not be used to modify the object, but something unknown to the implementation may modify the object.

Comment: I didn't say it can't be changed, it is a hint to the compiler that it won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Example for demonstrating const

```
  function1()
  {
      int i = 10;
      function2(&i);
  }
 function2(int const *ptr) // usage of const
 {
      *ptr = 20; //will cause error; outside function can't be modify the value of i
 }
```

Example for volatile

```
 function1()
 {
       while(1)
       {
             i = 20;

              print(i);
       }
 }

 function2()
 {
       i = 20;
       while(1)
       {
              print(i);
       }
 }
```

consider these two function. both are seem to be same. for optimisation  compiler convert function1 to function2. problem is that if value of i changed by another thread then two function become different, here while loop print value of i and another module change the value of i. so we will not get the value of i as 20 always.

volatile is used to inform the compiler not to optimise the variable.

Answer (score 0):

> The const modifier means that this code cannot change the value of the
>   variable, but that does not mean that the value cannot be changed by
>   means outside this code.

There are two different ways to apply the const qualifier.

A const-qualified *object* must not be modified by the program or the program has undefined behavior. A `const volatile` object can be modified by the OS/hardware/whatever, but not assigned to by the program. For the avoidance of doubt, a const object is one whose *definition* uses a const type for it.

A pointer-to-const-qualified-type prevents (at compile time) modifications via that pointer, but other pointers to the same object can be used to modify it. Behavior is defined provided the object itself is not const. However, the compiler may still assume that only the program modifies the object, accounting for arbitrary modifications by the OS/hardware/whatever require `volatile`.

A pointer-to-non-const-qualified-type is *exactly the same* as the pointer-to-const as far as modifications via other pointers are concerned.

However, volatile says "this data might be changed by something other than code in this program" and so the compiler will not make any assumptions about that data when optimizing.

So the differences are these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void some_other_function(const int *);

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int volatile b = 0;
    int const c = 0;
    int const *constptr = &a;
    int *ptr = (int*) constptr;

    printf("%d\n", a); // compiler can assume a == 0 at this point, and 
                       // replace the code with puts("0") if it wants to
    printf("%d\n", b); // compiler cannot assume a value for b, it's volatile[*]
    some_other_function(constptr); // defined in another TU
    printf("%d\n", a); // compiler can *no longer* assume that a == 0, 
                       // it might have changed
    *ptr = 1;          // there's another example of a changing, legally
    some_other_function(&c);
    printf("%d\n", c); // compiler can assume c == 0 because c is const
}
```

[*] Although I say it "can't assume a value", it may be that some hypothetical C implementation happens to know that there is no OS or hardware mechanism to modify an automatic variable by any means that would require `volatile` to detect. Especially in this case, where no reference to `b` has escaped the function. If so, then you might find that the implementation actually can ignore `volatile` in this particular code, but maybe it treats extern global `volatile` variables "properly" because it knows that the linker provides a means to map them to the addresses of I/O ports or whatever.

Comment: It is better to avoid the term “const-qualified object”. There is no such thing in the C standard, and this suggests a notion that it is the object that has the `const` property. In the C standard, it is a type, not an object, that may be const-qualified, and an lvalue may not be changed through a const-qualified type. This makes it clearer that it is the type through which an object is referred to that controls whether it is read-only or not, not the object, and hence makes it clearer that an object may be read-only when accessed one way and not read-only when accessed another way.

Comment: It would be incorrect for an implementation to “know” that an automatic volatile object cannot be modified. The definition of “volatile” is that an object may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation. There are tools capable of inspecting the internal state of a program, locating automatic objects, and modifying them.

Comment: @Eric: on what platform? If I build the hardware and write the C implementation, I can make it physically impossible for you to modify a volatile automatic variable with no reference-escape (at least, without voiding your warranty). I'm not claiming this is common.

Comment: You can build any hardware you want and implement anything you want for a compiler, but it is only a C compiler if it obeys the C specification. If it knows what it must not know, it violates the C specification. The most common tools for inspecting the internal state of a program are debuggers and humans. It is not uncommon to temporarily add “volatile” to a declaration to ensure it can be modified during debugging while trying to solve a difficult debugging problem.

Comment: @Eric: I guess that unlike you, I believe in the existence of platforms that don't have a debugger. I wish I didn't ;-) If there's no physical means to observe the behaviour that the standard calls "observable", then there's no means to determine whether or not the implementation implements the standard. I would argue that the standard cannot legislate what cannot be determined. The standard doesn't actually define what it means to read a memory location, though, so I believe the implementation would conform if there's no physical difference between "reading it" and "not reading it".

Comment: I suppose in essence I'm arguing for a meta "as-if" rule, beyond the scope of the standard or for that matter any standard. If the implementation behaves as if it implements the standard, to the extent that it can be observed, then it implements the standard. Epistemology ftw.

Comment: The existence of the debugger is not relevant; it is just an example. The relevant statement is the **requirement** of the standard that “volatile” means an object may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation.

Comment: That's not what the standard says. It says that the last store to a volatile object need not be explicit in the program (that is, it may happen in ways unknown to the *standard*), and that accesses to volatile objects by the program are observable behavior. It does not say that there must exist a mechanism to modify the object which lies outside the knowledge of the implementer. Implementations that provide no such mechanism can nevertheless conform, and the standard doesn't say that they must pretend that there is one when there isn't.

Comment: C 2011 6.7.3 7: “An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects.”

Comment: @Eric: keep reading, "... what constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined". The implementation is permitted to rule out modifications in some *or all* cases. Perhaps the precise wording is a defect in the standard (certainly it is if the intent is to mandate that there must exist such mechanisms). But in my experience "say something and then partially take it back" isn't unusual, and this is an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Volatile and Const can be easily see in bellow case,

1) If you say some variable as Const, it may not be possible to modify by your program.

2) if you say volatile, it is just giving a hint to the compiler not to optimize the code, because the value may be changed from the external threads or other programs.

3) if we define a variable as Const Volatile, that means this variable can not be modified by same program, will not be optimized by compiler and can be modified by external threads or programs.

example:

if i write a function like below,

```
const freq = 10;
calfreq()
{
return (Const freq * 2);
}
```

here in this case compiler may optimize the code to

```
return(20);
```

all the time.

But here in m y case, freq value may change, because of external hardware / threads / programs 
So, if i say Const Volatile, then problem will be fixed.