# What is the Difference between Constant and Volatile in C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, constants, volatile

what is the difference between Constant and Volatile

and

What is difference 
Volatile int i =10 
And
int i =10;

please let me briefly

Comment: One is constant and the other is not? Also check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822386/the-volatile-keyword-in-c-language and generally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable

Comment: Please search enough before asking questions. Related: [What are the differences between const and volatile pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089464/what-are-the-differences-between-const-and-volatile-pointer-in-c?lq=1)

Comment: you should specify the version of the language that you are targeting/using

Comment: @user2485710 They should also stick to one single language.

Comment: Yoiks! What do they have in common?

Comment: What's the difference between Panama and Apples?

Answer (score 1):

For a start

```
int i = 0;
```

Is not a constant, as it requires the `const` keyword. A constant cannot be modified and requires to be initialized (you can't put `const int i; i = 10;`)

Volatile [variables] can be modified externally, for example

```
asm volatile
```

Would state the the assembly code can be externally modified